# How to stop Behat tests in the middle to run element inspector?

Tags: debugging, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, behat

I'm using Chrome driver and currently to pause the browser in the middle of the tests I do:

```
And I ...
And I wait for 3600 seconds
And I ...
```

given the following method:

```
/**
 * @Given I wait for :number seconds
 */
public function iWaitForSeconds($number) {
  $this->getSession()->wait($number * 1000);
}
```

so I can freely use *DevTools* to inspect the objects of the given page at specific place in my tests.

The problem is that when opening *DevTools*, the script stops with error:

```
And I wait for 3600 seconds # CWTest\Context\HelperContext::iWaitForSeconds()
  disconnected: not connected to DevTools
    (Session info: chrome=59.0.3071.115)
    (Driver info: chromedriver=2.31.488774,platform=Mac OS X 10.12.0 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
  Command duration or timeout: 605 milliseconds
  Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
  Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
  Session ID: d429c9a3fdac50fcaed852d9f094d535 (WebDriver\Exception\UnknownError)
```

Is there any better way of doing that?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a breakpoint like this:

```
    /**
     * adds a breakpoints
     * stops the execution until you hit enter in the console
     * @Then /^breakpoint/
     */
    public function breakpoint()
    {
        fwrite(STDOUT, "\033[s    \033[93m[Breakpoint] Press \033[1;93m[RETURN]\033[0;93m to continue...\033[0m");
        while (fgets(STDIN, 1024) == '') {}
        fwrite(STDOUT, "\033[u");
        return;
    }
```

You can also declare it static an call it like `ClassName::breakpoint();`

As an alternative you could enable debugging in your IDE.

Comment: Nice answer, but I would definitely suggest debugging with IDE to avoid such hacks.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Behat step through extension](https://github.com/ciaranmcnulty/behat-stepthroughextension) which is a module that will allow you to easily to step through a certain feature without having to add specific code for it.  This is the GitHub overview:

> When debugging a particular scenario, use the `--step-through` flag at the CLI:

```
bin/behat --step-through features/my-failing-feature
```

> After each step you will see the message
>
> `[Paused after "<step text>" - press enter to continue]`
>
> The Behat test suite will stay in this suspended state until a carriage return is received, to allow you to do any inspections necessary.

Answer (score -1):

We can use sleep command for that.

```
sleep(500);
```