# Check a radio button with a specific value

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, behat, mink

I have this html :

```
<div class="c_row caption single" style="height: 89px;">
<label>
    <span>Question</span>
</label>
<div class="c_box radio-block" style="height: 88px;">
    <label style="width: 10%; font-size: initial; height: 88px;" class="radio">
    <input class="radio-button" type="radio" name="question_27" value="1" checked="">
    <span class="lb">1</span><i class="input-helper"></i></label><label style="width: 10%; font-size: initial; height: 88px;" class="radio">
    <input class="radio-button" type="radio" name="question_27" value="2">
    <span class="lb">2</span><i class="input-helper"></i></label><label style="width: 10%; font-size: initial; height: 88px;" class="radio">
    <input class="radio-button" type="radio" name="question_27" value="3">
    <span class="lb">3</span><i class="input-helper"></i></label><label style="width: 10%; font-size: initial; height: 88px;" class="radio">
    <input class="radio-button" type="radio" name="question_27" value="4">
    <span class="lb">4</span><i class="input-helper"></i></label><label style="width: 10%; font-size: initial; height: 88px;" class="radio">
    <input class="radio-button" type="radio" name="question_27" value="5">
    <span class="lb">5</span><i class="input-helper"></i></label><label style="width: 10%; font-size: initial; height: 88px;" class="radio">
    <input class="radio-button" type="radio" name="question_27" value="6">
    <span class="lb">6</span><i class="input-helper"></i></label><label style="width: 10%; font-size: initial; height: 88px;" class="radio">
    <input class="radio-button" type="radio" name="question_27" value="7">
    <span class="lb">7</span><i class="input-helper"></i></label><label style="width: 10%; font-size: initial; height: 88px;" class="radio">
    <input class="radio-button" type="radio" name="question_27" value="8">
    <span class="lb">8</span><i class="input-helper"></i></label><label style="width: 10%; font-size: initial; height: 88px;" class="radio">
    <input class="radio-button" type="radio" name="question_27" value="9">
    <span class="lb">9</span><i class="input-helper"></i></label><label style="width: 10%; font-size: initial; height: 88px;" class="radio">
    <input class="radio-button" type="radio" name="question_27" value="10">
    <span class="lb">10</span><i class="input-helper"></i></label>
</div>
<div class="c_box select-block hidden" style="height: 88px;">
        <select class="selectmenu" name="question_27" id="ui-id-2" style="display: none;">
            <option disabled="" selected="" value=""> -- </option>
            <option value="1" selected="">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option>
        </select>   
</div>
```

And I want to check the radio button but the problem is that works only for first value of radio. For example if I write :

```
And I select "1" from "question_27"
```

Works fine, but If I tried the second value :

```
And I select "2" from "question_27"
```

Doesn't work. I get the error that this value doesn't exist.

Can you help me please ? Thx in advance and sorry for my english

Comment: can you post the code you have tried. specially locator like xpath if you are using

Comment: I'm not using xpath. Only how I wrote : `And I select "2" from "question_27"`

Comment: ok its a php framework like yii framework

Comment: It's symfony project

Comment: Add the code what you have tried so far for selecting radio button

Comment: Like that : `And I select "2" from "question_27"`

Comment: Maybe you need a wait, do a debug, you can also try to put a `breakpoint` before and inspect. Also add the stack trace of the error, use `-vvv` for verbose. For breakpoint check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45423591/how-to-stop-behat-tests-in-the-middle-to-run-element-inspector

Comment: Shouldn't you use a click on the `input` ?